# Commands in ruby terminal application

Tags: ruby

I have just written my first terminal application in ruby. I use `OptionParser` to parse the options and their arguments. However I want to create commands. For example:

```
git add .
```

In the above line, `add` is the command which cannot occur anywhere else than immediately after the application. How do I create these.

I will appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. However, please do not reference any gems such as Commander. I already know about these. I want to understand how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OptionParser's [`parse!`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-parse-21) takes an array of arguments. By default, it will take `ARGV`, but you can override this behaviour like so:

#### Basic Approach

```rb
def build_option_parser(command)
  # depending on `command`, build your parser
  OptionParser.new do |opt|
    # ...
  end
end

args = ARGV
command = args.shift # pick and remove the first option, do some validation...
@options = build_option_parser(command).parse!(args) # parse the rest of it
```

#### Advanced Approach

Instead of a `build_option_parser` method with a huge case-statement, consider an OO approach:

```rb
class AddCommand
  attr_reader :options
  def initialize(args)
    @options = {}
    @parser = OptionParser.new #...
    @parser.parse(args)
  end
end

class MyOptionParser
  def initialize(command, args)
    @parser = {
      'add' => AddCommand,
      '...' => DotsCommand
    }[command.to_s].new(args)
  end
  def options
    @parser.options
  end
end
```

#### Alternatives

For sure, there exist [tons of Rubygems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers) (well, 20 in that list), which will take care of your problem. I'd like to mention [Thor](http://rubygems.org/gems/thor) which powers, e.g. the `rails` command line tool.

Comment: Cool. Exactly what I was looking for. However, instead of creating new class for every command, I will try to contain a command's function inside a block or something. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Using classes will force to think of an clean interface. And you could do some nifty things like `Kernel.const_get("#{command.to_s.capitalize}Command").new(args)`. Just sayin' :-)

Comment: @akashspeaking Another reason to use classes is that the functionality may be used in other ways, e.g., combined with other commands, and so on. It also allows better isolation for testing.

Comment: Also consider two commands `a` and `b` working with directories (and/or files). Where will you define the methods for the file/dir handling? You won't duplicate the code and you shouldn't pollute the Kernels method list. Using either a superclass (`class ACommand < ZBase`) or a mixin (`class ACommand; include DirHelper; ... end`) would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the command with `Array#shift` prior invoking `OptionParser`.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking along the same lines. I can create an interface where that command is recognized and appropriate action is taken. I'll start working on it. Thanks!